# How to add data for particular index in uitableview swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am creating a dynamic uilabel in CellforRowat for particuklar index i.e indexpath.row=0

But When I Scroll down I am seeing that UI Label on 4th Index  as well ....

Why is it coming on 3rd index if I have already added a condition in Cellforroat as:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // var cell:ActivityMainTableViewCell?

    if(CheckFlag == false){
        //CheckFlag = true
    }
    else{
        CheckFlag = false
    }
   // cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as? ActivityMainTableViewCell
    let cell:ActivityMainTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ActivityMainTableViewCell

   /// let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ActivityMainTableViewCell


    ///let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ActivityMainTableViewCell

   /// cell.viewheight.constant = 0
    cell.imgViewFirst.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.imgViewFirst.frame.size.width) / 2
    cell.imgViewFirst.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.imgViewFirst.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.imgViewFirst.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.ImageViewThird.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.ImageViewThird.frame.size.width) / 2
    cell.ImageViewThird.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.ImageViewThird.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.ImageViewThird.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.ImageViewSecond.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.ImageViewSecond.frame.size.width) / 2
    cell.ImageViewSecond.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.ImageViewSecond.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.ImageViewSecond.clipsToBounds = true
   print(indexPath)
    print(indexPath.row)
    print(dicArray)
    cell.DateOfMeeting.text = dicArray[indexPath.row]["Date"] as? String
    cell.CompanyInMeetiong.text = dicArray[indexPath.row]["Company"] as? String
    cell.lblNews.text = dicArray[indexPath.row]["News"]  as? String
    cell.lblCommonKey.text = dicArray[indexPath.row]["CommonKey"]  as? String


    print(SectordicArray)
    cell.imgViewFirst.isHidden = true


    cell.lblCommonKey.isHidden = true
    cell.btnOthers.tag = indexPath.row

    //for i in 0..<section.count {

    print(cell.lblCommonKey.text)
    print(indexPath.row)
    RowHeight = 110.0
    CellHeight = 140.0

    isFirstTime = true
   // print(AllCompanydicArray)
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
    let Data = AllCompanydicArray[indexPath.row]

    print(Data)
    for i in 0..<Data.count {

        print(Data[i])
            if(isFirstTime == false){
                RowHeight = RowHeight + 30.0
                CellHeight = CellHeight + 30.0
            }
            else{
                isFirstTime = false
            }
            let Company = (Data[i] as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Company") as! [String]
            let Contacts = (Data[i] as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Participants") as! [String]
            // section.append(Company)
            //items.append(Contacts)
        for k in 0..<Company.count {

            let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: RowHeight, width:cell.frame.width, height: 30.0))
            newLabel.text = Company[k]
            newLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13)
            cell.addSubview(newLabel)
        }
            for j in 0..<Contacts.count {
                RowHeight = RowHeight + 30.0
                CellHeight = CellHeight + 30.0

             var
                newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: RowHeight, width:30, height: 30.0))
                newLabel.text = CaptionName(Name: Contacts[j])
                //"RC"
                newLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 11)
                newLabel.textAlignment = .center
                newLabel.backgroundColor = getColorByHex(rgbHexValue: 0x002366, alpha: 0.9)// UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 14.0, blue: 40.0, alpha: 100.0)
                newLabel.layer.cornerRadius = (newLabel.frame.size.width) / 2
                newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                newLabel.clipsToBounds = true
                newLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                newLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

                cell.addSubview(newLabel)

                newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: RowHeight, width:cell.frame.width-30, height: 30.0))
                newLabel.text = Contacts[j]//"Raghav Chopra"
                newLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
                cell.addSubview(newLabel)

            }
    }
}
    else{



    }

    return cell
}
```

Please let me know how can i avoid uilabel on 4th index.

Comment: put else condition  and remove it from removeformSuperview

Comment: how can i achieve this

Comment: it's becuase cells are reused, so they will be replaced. you need to add some other property on your condition based on your model to check for that specific cell you want.

Comment: @RaghavChopra put your full code will give answer asap

Comment: @SaeidBasirnia If I dont want to use those cell how can i use a new cell

Comment: @SaeidBasirnia I want my label to be on first index only no where else

Comment: I have also search that we can remove all views in prepareforresue but when i am removing all view in the same by this it is not getting removed i am using    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        let rr = contentView.subviews
        print(rr.count)
        for i in 0..<rr.count {
            contentView.willRemoveSubview(rr[i])
        }
    }

Comment: im still not getting your exact use case. is it necessary to be first row of tableview? why not use a header view for this purpose and just collapse it when scrolling? @RaghavChopra